# Cannot upload file: *.png - CKEditor, CKFinder

Tags: reactjs, node.js, express, ckeditor

My API upload file (ExpressJS)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x5Lby.png)

My CKFinder on ReactJS
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C6ucZ.png)

Where did I go wrong, Can anyone help me?

--------------------- Sorry about my English ---------------------

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved my problem. If anyone still can't solve it, you can refer to my code.

API

```
    app.post("/files/upload", upload.single("upload"), function (req, res) {
     res.send({
     currentFolder: {
      url: `http://localhost:3007/images/${res.req.file.filename}`,
      acl: 255,
    },
    url: `http://localhost:3007/images/${res.req.file.filename}`,
    fileName: `${res.req.file.filename}`,
    uploaded: 1,
  });
});
```

ReactJS

```
ckfinder: {
 uploadUrl: "http://localhost:3007/files/upload"
}
```

The problem is: my API returns the wrong format.

If you see any problems with my code, please comment so I can fix it.

Thank ALL!!!!!

Reference: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckfinder/ckfinder3-php/commands.html#command_fileupload